# Why cannot a template template parameter be defaulted?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, overloading, template-templates

```
#include <string>

template
<
    typename CharType,
    template<class, class, class> class StringType = std::basic_string
    <CharType,  std::char_traits<CharType>, std::allocator<CharType>>
>
void f(CharType, StringType)
{}

int main()
{
    char c;
    std::string str;

    f(c, str);
    //
    // error : default template argument for
    //  a template template parameter must be a class template
    //
}
```

**Why cannot a `template template parameter` be defaulted?**

Comment: If you read the error message it says that "a template template parameter must be ***a class template***". `std::basic_string` by itself *is* a class template. `std::basic_string
    <CharType,  std::char_traits<CharType>, std::allocator<CharType>>` is *not* a template, it's a concrete class derived from the `std::basic_string` template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with

```
template
<
    typename CharType,
    template<class, class, class> class StringType = std::basic_string
>
void f(CharType, StringType<CharType, std::char_traits<CharType>,
                            std::allocator<CharType>>)
{}
```

`std::basic_string<CharType,  std::char_traits<CharType>, std::allocator<CharType>>` is a simple typename; if you want a `template<typename, typename, typename> class`, you have to throw away the template arguments and use the skeleton: `std::basic_string`

Comment: this only works for `StringType` implementations like the STL. Won't work for e.g. `const CharType*`

Comment: @virgesmith - sorry but I don't understand what do you mean; please, would you please prepare an example and post is as a question?

Comment: You've imposed that StringType is a template that takes 3 params, so e.g. f<char, const char*> couldnt be instantiated.  See my answer below.

Comment: @virgesmith - oh, yes; I've imposed three params because the OP imposed three params; if you want a template template parameter with a undefined number of parameters, you can write `template<typename...> class StringType = std::basic_string`

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, this is less restrictive on the StringType implementation:

```
#include <string>

template
<
    typename CharType,
    typename StringType = std::basic_string<CharType,std::char_traits<CharType>,std::allocator<CharType>>
>
void f(CharType, StringType)
{
}


int main()
{
    char c;
    std::string str;

    f(c, str);

    const char* cstring;

    f(c, cstring); // also works
}
```